# AjaxFileupload Giving Error only in shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

By hosting I get an error when using Ajaxfileupload.

```
"*System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find part of the path "C: \ Windows \ TEMP \ _AjaxFileUpload \ F0815340-BAEA-E056-B62F-F33770BBEDF4*"."
```

The code:

```
string filePath = "~/folder/"+e.filename;
AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));
```

Comment: I think you have to change the default temp directroy that asp.net uses to store uploads temporarily. Usually on shared hosts you do not have access to the c:\windows\temp folder. try: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/viag/archive/2006/10/25/how-to-change-the-default-tempfile-upload-location-for-the-asp-net-2-0-fileupload-control.aspx

Comment: <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" tempDirectory="C:/Users/LocalUser/../../Temp/">

Comment: In asp.net do Response.Write(MapPath(filePath)) to get the system path to where you want to upload the file and also make that your temporary path. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

In your hosting folder there will be `Set Up Access Permissions` and then just do `Plesk IIS Worker Process Identity Account (your account)` in `permissions Full Control make selected`

Comment: Standard fileupload normally saves files in this folder

Comment: normally in hosting server you have to give permission for path access other wise it gives error path not found,,

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Web.Config

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  <system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try checking for Directory existence before saving the file to the folder**

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("folderpath"))
{
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("folderpath");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running in Integrated Mode pool, you have to add this lines in the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler,            AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </handlers>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```